# Upgrading uTorrent 2.x to 3.x behind a router

Tags: router, bittorrent, upload, utorrent

After upgrading uTorrent version from 2.x to 3.x some torrents get `the requested address is not valid in its context` in tracker statuses. Upload speed on such torrents is very slow or none. Downgrading to uTorrent 2.x fixes the problem. How to get 3.x working?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably have set `net.outgoing_ip` to your internet address (for example, 192.0.43.10) some time earlier for seeding behind a router. This option backfires on new version of uTorrent. To fix the strange behavior of the client you should open preferences->advanced, scroll to `net.outgoing_ip` option and reset it to blank. Your slow torrents should become alive after uTorrent restart.

Comment: D.I.D.?​​​​​​​​

Comment: Answering my own question, Q&A-style. That's an option when you want to share a non-googlable knowledge.